# Allocating memory to AudioSampleBuffer at run time, rather than a fixed buffer size

Tags: c++, audio, memory, buffer, juce

I am writing a simple recording application, and at the moment, the audio records to an AudioSampleBuffer with a fixed amount of memory. The size of the buffer is declared here in the static const int "BufferSize":

```
//Audio data
static const int bufferSize = 352800; //constant
unsigned int bufferPosition;
AudioSampleBuffer audioSampleBuffer;
```

Is there a way to allocate memory to the buffer as the user is recording, then stop when the user has stopped recording?

Comment: Is `bufferSize` the *largest* the buffer can get? Then why not simply allocate it all at once? You *do* know how to allocate memory in C++ (the `new` keyword)?

Comment: Yes it is, but I don't want it to be. I don't want their to be a limit on how large the buffer can be, so the user can record audio for as long as they wish

Comment: Then how about using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as the buffer? [Reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) a chunk of memory to begin with (to avoid excessive reallocation) and when the vector is about to become full reserve a larger chunk and continue appending data.